# Create a mask from a boundingRect in openCV

Tags: opencv

Lets say I was given a boundingRect based on some points and stored it into a Rect object.

How can I use those points and create a mask in openCV? that is, everything outside the bounding rectangle is masked (or set white)

I've tried several different methods and was able to get it to work using a convexHull and fillign with a polygon but can't seem to get it to work with the boundingRect

Comment: You will have a better chance of getting a helpful response if you post some of the code you tried.

Comment: Better tag with the language you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [**`fillConvexPoly()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillconvexpoly) by passing the four end points of the bounding `Rect`.

```
// assume all four end points are stored in "vector<Point> roi_vertices" already
// the order of the vertices don't matter

Mat mask = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));

// Create Polygon from vertices
vector<Point> roi_poly;
approxPolyDP(roi_vertices, roi_poly, 1.0, true);

// Fill polygon white
fillConvexPoly(mask, &roi_poly[0], (int)roi_poly.size(), 255, 8, 0);
```

---

**P.S.**: the above method will also work for generating masks for any (convex) polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Draw your rectangle with CV_FILLED option and invert it, like

```
Rect boundRect(x,y,W,H);
Mat mask(rows,cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar(0));
rectangle(mask,boundRect,Scalar(255),CV_FILLED,8,0);
bitwise_not(mask,mask);
```

or in another way without using invert, just create a white image and then draw rectangle using CV_FILLED option but with black color(Scalar(0)).

That is

```
Rect boundRect(x,y,W,H);
Mat mask(rows,cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar(255));
rectangle(mask,boundRect,Scalar(255),CV_FILLED,8,0);
```